# Changing whats new in this version text - iPhone

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I uploaded the binary to the app store and afterwards found an issue with the app. I would like to change the binary and the "whats new in this version" text but that field is not editable. Is that not allowed anymore?

Comment: is the binary still in review?

Answer (score 0):

if you are changing the binary after its been on sale, it has to be a new version (numerically higher than the previous version). When you upload the binary for the new version, you can edit the field.

You can change the whats new text when its on sale. (I just checked that I can change the whats new text for one of my apps thats currently on sale)

Answer (score 0):

iTunesConnect store, after submitting a version for review today, says;

> You can only edit all information while your version is waiting for
>   review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from
>   review.